# How to get a file path from Shiny UI, and access the file from there

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to choose a file (for example dataset) through the shiny app, which will then give some basic outputs such as str(), summary(), and describe() (Hmisc package).
the dataset could be iris or cars in this case.

I would be grateful for some help, couldn't figure it out myself.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)


ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyFilesButton("Btn_GetFile", "Choose a file" ,
                   title = "Please select a file:", multiple = FALSE,
                   buttonType = "default", class = NULL),
  
  textOutput("txt_file")     
)


server <- function(input,output,session){
  
  volumes = getVolumes()
  observe({  
    shinyFileChoose(input, "Btn_GetFile", roots = volumes, session = session)
    
    if(!is.null(input$Btn_GetFile)){
      # browser()
      file_selected<-parseFilePaths(volumes, input$Btn_GetFile)
      output$txt_file <- renderText(as.character(file_selected$datapath))
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I have never found a situation where having nested reactive functions (`observe`, `reactive`, or `render*`) made any sense (or even worked well). Do not nest them.

   Related to this, `shinyFileChoose` must be outside of other reactive blocks.
2. `getVolumes()` returns a *function*, so in your example, `volumes = getVolumes()`, your variable `volumes` is a function ... which does not do what you want. Try `getVolumes()()`. Perhaps this is confusing ... I don't know enough about the package to understand this design decision, but the docs are clear about this point. (It has something to do with the sentence: *"dynamic so that a shinyFiles instance reflects new volumes as they get added"*, though `shinyFilesExample()` does not seem to attempt to be dynamic about it? Idk.)
3. I'm inferring here, but your choice of `txt_file` as a name suggests that you intend to show the *contents* of the selected file, not its name or actually the `data.frame` that the `shinyFiles` tools are giving you. I'll provide both options, where `$selected_file()` provides the returned structure (`data.frame` that includes the file(s) name, path, etc), and `$file_contents()`, which is the raw contents of the file itself. (I'll truncate to a couple of lines for brevity.)

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyFilesButton("Btn_GetFile", "Choose a file" ,
                   title = "Please select a file:", multiple = FALSE,
                   buttonType = "default", class = NULL),
  tableOutput("selected_file"),
  verbatimTextOutput("file_contents")
)

server <- function(input,output,session){
  volumes = getVolumes()()
  shinyFileChoose(input, "Btn_GetFile", roots = volumes, session = session)
  file_selected <- eventReactive(input$Btn_GetFile, {
    req(input$Btn_GetFile)
    parseFilePaths(volumes, input$Btn_GetFile)
  })
  output$file_contents <- renderText({
    req(nrow(file_selected()) > 0,
        file.exists(file_selected()$datapath))
    readLines(file_selected()$datapath, n = 2)
  })
  # optional, purely informative, can safely be removed along with UI component
  output$selected_file <- renderTable({
    req(nrow(file_selected()) > 0)
    file_selected()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I found running `shinyFilesExample()` to be instructive in researching this question.